nfs v4 mount failing with operation not permitted over ssh tunnel
I have two Ubuntu Linux machines. One server and other client. The server is hosting a nfs v4 server sharing the /nfs-share directory.
I am attempting nfs v4 mount over ssh tunnel for the following reasons:

confidentiality
simplicity
no need to open nfs ports on firewalld
access control : users having access to ssh can mount the nfs share

I have chosen nfs v4 specifically to avoid the need for rpcbind, statd, mountd etc which would require aditional ports for nfs v3 to work.
/etc/exports:
—————————————————
/nfs-share  *(sec=sys,rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)

The above is the only exported directory from the server.
I have verified mount of the nfs directory both from local node (i.e. server) as well as client and all works perfectly fine…
However, when I attempt the nfs mount over a ssh tunnel I get the error: Operation not permitted. And this issue is observed even when I create a local ssh tunnelon server from port 2049 to 4049 as well.
This is how I have tried setting up the tunnel from the client:
—————————————————————————————
root@client:~# ssh -fqNTL 127.0.0.1:2049:127.0.0.1:2049 root@13.221.112.100
root@client:~# mount -vvv -o vers=4,proto=tcp 127.0.0.1:/nfs-share /mnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Dec 12 22:40:45 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'proto=tcp,vers=4.2,addr=127.0.0.1,clientaddr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted

And also the following way:
—————————————————————————————————————
root@client:~# ssh -fqNTL 127.0.0.1:4049:127.0.0.1:2049 root@13.221.112.100
root@client:~# mount -vvv -o vers=4,proto=tcp,port=4049 127.0.0.1:/nfs-share /mnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Dec 12 22:42:34 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'proto=tcp,port=4049,vers=4.2,addr=127.0.0.1,clientaddr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted

I have also verified with tcpdump that the nfs client’s requests are actually reaching the server:
————————————————————————————————————————————————
root@server:~# tcpdump -vv -i any dst port 2049
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
22:42:30.128843 lo    In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24532, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    localhost.51734 > localhost.nfs: Flags [S], cksum 0xfe30 (incorrect -> 0x4d2d), seq 2290211965, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2614046702 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:42:30.129019 lo    In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24533, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.51734 > localhost.nfs: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x54f2), seq 2290211966, ack 812262091, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2614046702 ecr 2614046702], length 0
22:42:30.130879 lo    In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24534, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 96)
    localhost.51734 > localhost.nfs: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfe54 (incorrect -> 0x2f49), seq 0:44, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2614046704 ecr 2614046702], length 44: NFS request xid 1800123220 40 null
22:42:30.131151 lo    In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24535, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.51734 > localhost.nfs: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x54a6), seq 44, ack 29, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2614046704 ecr 2614046704], length 0

What is going on wrong and how can I make it work?

Thanks @ user508954 for providing the solution to the issue on another question.
Adding the insecure option to my share in /etc/exports resolved this issue. So the cause was nfs server not accepting connections from ports greater than 1000.
I believe ssh also allows binding to a local port with -D option. Not sure if ssh tunnel will follow this option when port forwarding... If it does, the other way cauld be to bind ssh to a port <1000 on the client when setting up the tunnel.
I have secured my nfs server by setting 127.0.0.1 as the allowed hosts in my nfs exports and also removing nfs/rpc etc from firewall rules. Now only ssh users who have access to the server can setup a tunnel and mount the nfs on the client.
